# Routing to a Specific Id Path in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to set up routing so that when a user clicks on a certain name, that the app navigates to that correct component, with the correct id that is passed in. I have set it up according to how I understand it to work in Angular 2, but I'm getting an "undefined id" error when I run it. This is what I have:

In my component view the relevant code looks like this:

```
       <td><a [routerLink]="['/person', person.id]">{{record.name.first}} {{record.name.last}}</a></td>
```

... And in my routing I have this:

```
{ path: 'person/:id', component: PersonView },
```

The actual url being navigated to for a specific "person" looks like this:

> http://localhost:4200/person/3249aae3d4c9as7ca0623781

The specific error I'm getting is:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

What am I missing here?

Comment: It says you don't have person object containing id property. Do you have?

Comment: actually your person don't have any value. what value you are passing in person.id ??

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass in the correct value there. How do I determine that?

Comment: here is the live plnkr. it will help https://plnkr.co/edit/5R0URH14ZiVjx81HEZxL?p=preview

Comment: Where are you reading the id parameter?

Comment: Also why are you trying to navigate on click of an anchor pointing to same routes?

Comment: Are you saying the "onSelect()" method is unnecessary here?

Comment: Yes its not needed here when you have already setup [routerLink] in your anchor

Comment: Good point. I'll remove that. Still need to figure out how to pass in id though.

Comment: do you have a typo? `person.id` instead of `record.id`?

Comment: Rudolph, you were onto it here. I needed "record", not "person" in the second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end, I had the routing structured correctly, but, as Boyan and Rudolph correctly pointed out, the issue was with needing to pass "record" in as the second parameter, rather than "person", since that's how I am parsing data from the api.

```
<td><a [routerLink]="['/person', record._id ]">{{record.name.first}} {{record.name.last}}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with what you are are doing:

1. You are navigating "twice". Both in the anchor tag, and then in the onSelect. You don't need both, pick one. I recommend you use the [routerLink] unless you really need to do something else before you navigate.
2. You are not passing the ID in the right way. It should be in the form:

   ['../', { id: crisisId, foo: 'foo' }]

Or in your case:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/person', { id: record._id }]"...
```

Check out the Angular 2 docs on routing: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

**Update:**

I should have paid more attention. You are getting undefined because "person" is not the object that has the ID. Use "record.id" because you are using "record" as your object that contains the person ID, correct?

Comment: I removed the onSelect method, because, I agree, it is unnecessary. And I changed the routerLink as you suggested, but it's still undefined.

Comment: Updated my answer, silly mistake on my part not noticing that.

Comment: Thanks. I am close now. You're right about "record". Now I am using this:
<td><a [routerLink]="['/person', { id: record._id} ]">{{record.name.first}} {{record.name.last}}</a></td>

Comment: I'm close because when I hover over the link, in the bottom left of my browser I can see it's getting the id now. But when I click it goes to the root of the app, suggesting maybe I just need to adjust the routing file.

Comment: My routing looks like this:
{ path: 'person/:id', component: PersonView }

Comment: It does, I don't think it's an issue with your route definition.

Comment: A sample route is: http://localhost:4200/person/5249aae4e4c6hr7ca0638781

Comment: When I hover over the link now, in the bottom left corner I see this:
/person;id=3843aaf5e2c9ad8ar0639eq2

Comment: I think that's the problem. Right route - but with a semi-colon injected instead of a slash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134022/discussion-between-boyan-kostadinov-and-muirik).

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the parameters in ngOnInit

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
export class LiveAuctionComponent implements OnInit
{
    ngOnInit() {
        //read parameters here
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.Id = params["id"];
        });
    }

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){

    }
}
```

You are passing the parameter correctly with

```
<a [routerLink]="['/person', person.id]">.. </a>  <= person.id (make sure person is populated or initialized in your component)
```

Assuming your URL looks like this

> http://localhost:4200/person/3249aae3d4c9as7ca0623781

your id in component should be 3249aae3d4c9as7ca0623781 after the above code is executed.

Comment: Two thoughts: so the route.params.subscribe is necessary here? Also, what is "auctionId" referring to here?

Comment: I copied this section from my snippet, I have edited auctionId as Id which is my variable in my angular component

Comment: Subscribe will update the value of your parameters whenever they change, so I am not sure ifs necessary here but no harm

Answer (score 0):

Please note `[routerLink]="['/person', person.id]"` and **`2)`** both are technically equivalent. So you can use one of them. Not sure how to use **`person.id`** in your case. But just for the understanding purpose you can pass static value.

So use **either**,

**1)**

```
 <td><a [routerLink]="['/person', 5]"      //<<---passing static value 5
        (click)="onSelect(person)">{{record.name.first}} {{record.name.last}}</a></td>
```

**OR**

**2)**

```
onSelect(person) {
    this.router.navigate(['/person', 5]);
}
```

---

**EDIT**: answer to your comment.

In order to use dynamic value instead of static, you need to get it from server or set in your javascript/typescript as shown using any variable/object.

```
export class app{
 constructor{
  this.person={id:5}  // 5 can be replaced if you try to get the value from the server. That way it will become dynamic.
 }
}
```

And then

```
onSelect(person) {
        this.router.navigate(['/person', person.id]);  /<<<---now person.id has 5 value.
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I removed the unnecessary onSelect method. Re: the value being passed in, it's easy enough when it's static, but how do you pass in a dynamic value?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this id as Query parameter, its the best and good way to pass id.

Here i will describe the steps to do so.

1. import router from angular-router

   import { Router } from '@angular/router';
2. Decleare a variable with router class inside the constructor

   ```
    constructor(_router: Router) {
     this.router = _router;
     }
   ```
3. Call a function on click event (assume it as onClick());
4. Inside on click write the code

   onClick(routeLink,id) {
       this.router.navigate([routeLink], { queryParams: { p1:id} });
     }

(here the function input two parameters as rout link and id as your need you can hard code route link and pass id only.)

Hope this will work for you.

more ref : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters

Answer (score -1):

Getting undefined Value instead of actual value

Step 01 : Routing Module code

{path:'ServicesComplaint/:id', component:ServicescomplaintComponent}

Step 02 :

Kitchen Appliances Repair

Step 03 :

ngOnInit() {

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.Id = params["id"];
  alert(this.Id);
  console.log(this.Id);
```

});